# XMLhttprequest error="CORS" failed

Tags: javascript, http

Выбивается ошибка CORS failed при попытки сделать запрос с помощью XMLhttprequest, вроде как поставил нужные хэдеры, но все равно CORS ругается

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var body = {
            email: this.state.email,
            number: this.state.number,
            password: this.state.password,
        }
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://test.tmc.ru/service/register', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json')
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://test.tmconsulting.ru/customer-service/register')
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readState !== 4) return;

            console.log(this.responceText)
        }
        xhr.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log(error.error)
        }
        xhr.send(body)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целях безопасности браузеры ограничивают cross-origin запросы, инициируемые скриптами. Например, XMLHttpRequest и Fetch API следуют политике одного источника (same-origin policy). Это значит, что web-приложения, использующие такие API, могут запрашивать HTTP-ресурсы только с того домена, с которого были загружены, пока не будут использованы CORS-заголовки.

Или другими словами Это сервер должен ответить с соответствующими заголовками.

Подробнее [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)